# How to make Nodemailer trigger a seperate .js script

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodemailer

So i have the main nodejs server file (myserver.js)

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const port = 80; 
const vectorExpress = require("./node_modules/@smidyo/vectorexpress-nodejs/index");
const fs = require("fs");
var cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());

app.use(express.json())

var randomnum = require('./randomnum.js');
var number = randomnum.number;


app.post('/mail', (req, res)=>{
  console.log(req.body)
  

  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'Gmail', 
    auth: {
        user: '',
        pass: ''
    }
});

  
const mailOptions = {
from: req.body.email,
to: 'naizeylines.info@gmail.com', 
subject: `Order from ${req.body.name}`,
text: 
`${req.body.name}  
${req.body.street}
${req.body.postcode} ${req.body.town}
${req.body.country}

Quantity: ${req.body.quantity}
Additional information:
${req.body.message}

Shipping address:
${req.body.name2}  
${req.body.street2}
${req.body.postcode2} ${req.body.town2}
${req.body.country2}
${req.body.phone2}

Email: ${req.body.email}
Phone number: ${req.body.phone}

File number: ${number}

    `,
    attachments: [{   // utf-8 string as an attachment
      path: `${number}.svg`,
      },
      {
      path: `${number}.dxf`,
      },
    ]
  }
  
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info)=>{
    if(error){
      console.log(error);
      res.send('error');
    }else{
      console.log('Email sent:' + info.response);
      res.send('success');
    }
  })
})
 

var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
```

and a seperate script file (randomnum.js)

```
function randomnumber() {
  return Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000);
}

var number = randomnumber();
exports.number = number;
console.log(number);
```

i would like to have it so that everytime nodemailer sends an email the main script would run the randomnum.js so that i would get a new random number generated. been trying for a few days now but i think im in over my head with my limited knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Based on code you provided, I see one obvious issue. You are defining randomnum out of the POST request. Also If i were you I'd generate random number inside of the myserver.js file.

Try this bit of code:

```
app.post('/mail', (req, res)=>{
  var number = Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000)
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
   service: 'Gmail', 
   auth: {
      user: '',
      pass: ''
   }
   }); REST OF YOUR POST REQUEST LOGIC.....
```

Comment: ok soo i need the number to change after every mail that is sent. assigning the random number in myserver.js is a one time number generation, it only generates a number on the initial run. i tried the first suggestion but the file name was not a number but this [object Object].svg (using random number to name a file)

Comment: Alright I see, in this case you have to define number variable inside of the post request so everytime request hits this endpoint new number would be created. Currently it is defined outside of the request so it would not be changed everytime you send the email. I will edit my answer now so you can see the code snippet.

Comment: sorry for not disclosign this but there is more to the myserver.js code. i didnt want to share my entire code on the internet but i need the number variable before i send the email because i need it for a file that is saved separately from the email. so if i do it the way you did now i do not have the variable ready before i send the email.

Answer (score -1):

Put Nodemailer code in separate file and export in main.js file and use with pass your data from main.js file

Hope this code will help to you

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config({});

export class SendEmail {
  public static send(data) {
    const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
      name: process.env.SMTP_HOST,
      host: process.env.SMTP_HOST,
      port: process.env.SMTP_PORT,
      auth: {
        user: process.env.SMTP_USER_NAME,
        pass: process.env.SMTP_PASSWORD,
      },
      pool: true, // use pooled connection
      rateLimit: true, // enable to make sure we are limiting
      maxConnections: 1, // set limit to 1 connection only
      maxMessages: 3, // send 3 emails per second
    });

    var mailOptions = {
      from: process.env.FROM,
      html: data.html,
      replyTo: process.env.REPLY_TO,
      to: data.to,
      subject: data.subject,
      text: data.text,
    };
    transport.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
      if (error) {
        return console.log(error);
      }
      console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);
      return;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: and how will this help me? could you explain in more detail?